# Magento 2.1 :- During compilation Fatal error

Tags: extensions, magento-2.1, compilation

I complete my own module. Now when i run the below command for compilation. I got the error.
Run this command for compilation :- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\ArgumentsResolver::getConfiguredInstanceArgument() must be of the type array, string given, called in /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php on line 125 and defined in /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php:169
Stack trace:
#0 /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php(125): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\ArgumentsResolver->getConfiguredInstanceArgument('test_demo')
#1 /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php(106): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\ArgumentsResolver->getConfiguredArgument('test_demo', Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\ConstructorArgument))
#2 /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/Config/Reader.php(121): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Compiler\ArgumentsResolver->getResolvedConstructorArguments('Test\\Demo\\Mo...', Array)
# in /mage2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php on line 169
```

Now I commented line in this file **app/code/Test/Demo/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLosamion="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Test\Demo\Api\Data\DemoItemInterface"
                type="Test\Demo\Model\Demo" />
    <preference for="Test\Demo\Api\Data\SampleItemInterface"
                type="Test\Demo\Model\Sample" />

    <virtualType name="DemoGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="DemoGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">DemoGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- <virtualType name="Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">Test_Demo</argument>            
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType> -->

    <virtualType name="DemoSampleGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="SamGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">DemoSampleGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- <virtualType name="Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">Test_Demo_sam</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType> -->

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Demotab_Demo_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="Demo_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="Sample_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

And 100% compilation done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now solve the issue.
I use below code. I removed two line and solved issue. And also all functionality are working perfect.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLosamion="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Test\Demo\Api\Data\DemoItemInterface"
                type="Test\Demo\Model\Demo" />
    <preference for="Test\Demo\Api\Data\SampleItemInterface"
                type="Test\Demo\Model\Sample" />

    <virtualType name="DemoGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="DemoGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">DemoGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>            
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="DemoSampleGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="SamGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">DemoSampleGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Demotab_Demo_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="Demo_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="Sample_index_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Test\Demo\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

Now compilation is 100% done.